# breaking up fractions

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

I have these two fractions

${11 \over 31 }+{-11 \over 61}$

Adding them gives

$330 \over 1891$

But how do I go back to the two fractions, once I've added them?

I can get the denominators just by factoring 1891, but how do I find the numerators without brute force?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Factor the denominator: $${330 \over 1891} = \frac {330}{31\cdot 61} = \frac A{31} + \frac B{61}$$

Then we need to find $$A\cdot 61 + B\cdot 31 = 330\tag{$\dagger$}$$ The problem then becomes finding integers $A, B$ that satisfy this equation $(\dagger)$. To do this, try using [Euclid's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Linear_Diophantine_equations), or the [\Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: I find the Extended Euclidean Algorithm a nice bit faster than brute force.

Comment: I meant the Extended algorithm...

Comment: How do I generalize this to 3 or more fractions?

Comment: @amWhy: Already looks like an excellent day to me! ;-) +1

Comment: enjoy the uni, @Babak!

Answer (score 1):

Every fraction can be decomposed into infinitely many other fractions. For instance, $1/2=1/12321+12319/24642$. So there's no hope.

Comment: True. Let me add a restriction, to make the output more useful: all of the denominators must be prime numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find integers $m$ and $n$ such that $$61m + 31n = 330.$$

For this you use [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Linear_Diophantine_equations).

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got around to writing a library to do this.

Link to [github](https://github.com/nickodell/break_fract).